# Is it possible to build qtHaskell 1.1.4 using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: haskell

I have written an application in C++/Qt that runs on Windows and I want to port it to Haskell/Qt using qtHaskell. Can I use  Visual C++ to build qtHaskell or I have to install MinGW/Qt?

Comment: What does the docs say?

Comment: The docs say to use MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't mix and match c++ compilers because they make different ABI choices. So you should do what the docs say and use MinGW/Qt.